# Guess is it npm conflict in digitalocean and pm2 status errored

Tags: npm, digital-ocean, yarnpkg, pm2

my local machine is use nvm to control node version. i create a nextJs app and deploy it into my server which host in digitalOcean cause pm2 status errored.

Is there possible happen cause conflict since node different version?

Page show **502 bad gateway**

Try to debug

> pm2 logs

```
11|selfpat | /tmp/yarn--1619166551597-0.6282906920762092/yarn:3
11|selfpat | exec "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/share/yarn/bin/yarn.js" "$@"
11|selfpat |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
11|selfpat | 
11|selfpat | SyntaxError: Unexpected string
11|selfpat |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
11|selfpat |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
11|selfpat |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
11|selfpat |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
11|selfpat |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
11|selfpat |     at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:303:25
11|selfpat |     at wrapper (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16)
11|selfpat |     at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:96:20)
11|selfpat |     at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
11|selfpat |     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Utility.js:186:13)
```

DO Server:

```
$ yarn --version > 1.22.5
$ npm --version > 6.14.8
$ node --version > v14.15.1
which node > /usr/bin/node
```

Run this before in DO Terminal shell not any respond

> npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path true

Local machine

```
$ yarn --version > 1.22.10
$ npm --version > 6.14.12
$ node --version > v14.16.1
which node > .nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node
```

Comment: Did you manage to work this out? I'm having the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

pm2 start yarn **--interpreter bash** --name <some_instance_name> -- start

Instead of this:

pm2 start yarn --name <some_instance_name> -- start

Comment: Have to format command line with code format.